How to assign tuple contents to individual variables
I have a code that creates a POLYGON. There a 5 points representing 5 x/y pairs (the last being a repeat of the first to 'close' the polygon.
I can produce it either as a shapely polygon or a standard tuple, both shown below.
POLYGON ((469444.168 8035483.527, 478263.094 8043038.430, 478100.448 8043228.289, 469281.522 8035673.385, 469444.168 8035483.527))
<class 'shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon'>

(((469444.168, 8035483.527), (478263.094, 8043038.430), (478100.448, 8043228.289), (469281.522, 8035673.385), (469444.168, 8035483.527)),)
<class 'tuple'>

I would like to assign each of the 8 coordinates to a separate variable so I can use them later for other calculations. x1/y1 to x4/y4 (no need for x5/y5 as they are duplicates)
x1 = 469444.168
y1 = 8035483.527
x2 = 478263.094
y2 = 8043038.430 ...etc

I have tried various tuple unpack methods but I can't seem to get the syntax correct, or it doesn't work with nested tuples like this. How do I assign the 8 individual variables from the Polygon or Tuple?

This is a one time operation, you dont want something that works for any number of vertices?

To assign the values stored in a nested tuple to as many variables, you need to replicate the very structure of the tuple to unpack it:
(((x1,y1),(x2,y2),(x3,y3),(x4,y4),(x5,y5)),) = (((469444.168, 8035483.527), (478263.094, 8043038.430), (478100.448, 8043228.289), (469281.522, 8035673.385), (469444.168, 8035483.527)),)

print(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4,x5,y5) # -> 469444.168 8035483.527 478263.094 8043038.43 478100.448 8043228.289 469281.522 8035673.385 469444.168 8035483.527

As suggested by @Pieter in a comment, you can avoid to unpack the 5th couple of coordinates (using the iterable unpacking and the conventional single underscore throwaway variable):
(((x1,y1),(x2,y2),(x3,y3),(x4,y4),*_),) = (((469444.168, 8035483.527), (478263.094, 8043038.430), (478100.448, 8043228.289), (469281.522, 8035673.385), (469444.168, 8035483.527)),)

print(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4) # -> 469444.168 8035483.527 478263.094 8043038.43 478100.448 8043228.289 469281.522 8035673.385


It is best to assign variables that won't be used (x5, y5) to underscore, so (_, _). This way python and linters know that you explicitly don't want to use those values further on in the code.

Thanks @Pieter. I've mentioned your suggestion (slightly modified) to my answer.
